# Hide A Div With CSS Only

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to hide a div with css only when you click a link. I'm making a popup that needs to be able to close when there is no JS. I've tried various methods but they have not worked when the button is inside the div that needs to hide.

Comment: Can you please post one method that you have tried....

Comment: Is there a way to do it with noscript then?

Comment: And no I cannot I don't commit to GitHub that frequently so it is lost sorry. @Coding...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when the button is inside the div that needs to hide.

<strike>Short answer: No, you can't achieve this when the button is inside the element.</strike> <sup>Thanks [Joseph Marikle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph-marikle)</sup>

<strike>However, you can achieve this when the button is outside the div.</strike>

```css
#hide {
  display: none;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#hide:checked ~ #randomDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hide" />


<div id="randomDiv">
  This is a div
  <label for="hide">Hide div</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Would noscript be able to do it? I'm not familiar with how it works so sorry if I'm completely wrong. Also I could use a keyframe on click to move the checkbox out of site.

Comment: Would noscript be able to hide the div with the button inside of it? Sorry, I'm clueless.

Comment: "Short answer: No". Yes you can too.  Just use the `for` attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/b3981op4/1

Comment: @JosephMarikle Awesome! Thanks, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @Lachlan to clarify, when using the `for` attribute, it should correlate to an `input` with an ID of whatever the `for` attribute is set to.  In the demo, the two labels trigger the input with the ID of "hide" because they have the attribute `for="hide"`.

Answer (score 0):

The following example hides the div when the checkbox is checked.

It uses the `#closebutton ~ #targetdiv {...` selector wich only works with its elements on this order. So the checkbox is placed inside of the main div on the layout but before of it on the code.

```css
.main {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#A {
  background: gold;
}

#B {
  background: skyblue; 
}

#C {
  background: yellowgreen; 
}

.close {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.close:checked {
  display: none;
}

.close:checked ~ #A, .close:checked ~ #B, .close:checked ~ #C {
  display: none;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;  
}
```

```html
<div id=groupA><input class="close" type="checkbox">
<div id=A class=main>info A</div></div>

<div id=groupB><input class="close" type="checkbox">
<div id=B class=main>info B</div></div>

<div id=groupC><input class="close" type="checkbox">
<div id=C class=main>info C</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        #hide{
            z-index: 10000;
            position: relative;
            top: -54px;
            padding: ;
            width: 9%;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 22px;
        }
        #hide:checked~h2{
            display: block;
        }
        h2{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Click me</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hide" />
    <h2>I'll appear when you click h1 !!!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```