# Hide div of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="checkbox"><input value="Yes" name="beta_interest" class="checkbox-input" id="beta_interest" type="checkbox"> <label for="beta_interest" class="checkbox-label icon-checkmark">Are you interested in joining program?</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input value="Yes" name="opt_in" class="checkbox-input" id="opt_in" type="checkbox"> <label for="opt_in" class="checkbox-label icon-checkmark">Yes, I’m interested in receiving announcements</label></div>
```

I need to hide or show the second div based on some dropdown condition.  How do I hide or show?

Comment: You may also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622147/hide-a-div-with-css-only The demo on that one shows how to do it with a checkbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

This question is horribly worded, but you're answer is to use the `.hide()` extension. Just use `$('elementIdentifier').hide();`

Comment: This does not seem to work

Comment: @user3276594 do you have JQuery added?

Comment: Yes i have added the jquery libarary and it loads fine.I need to hide the div of the input element which has id="opt_in"

Comment: Then use an id identifier for opt_in ($('#opt_in').hide();)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the style property of the `div`:

`style=display:none;`

and to show the `div`:

`style=display:inline;`

Answer (score 0):

Use change function on dropdown and then hide your div according to condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divChanger').change(function() {
    var value = $("#divChanger").val();
    if (value == 1) {
      $("#first").hide();
    }
    if (value == 2) {
      $("#second").hide();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<select id="divChanger">
  <option vlaue="">Select here</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<div id="first">
  <h1>
I am First Div
</h1>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <h1>
I am second div
</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qLvLLuq/) for example.